# communication between sharedworkers

Tags: javascript, shared-worker

I am working on an app in which has child apps. I am trying to use shared workers.
One shared worker will be used for websockets and another one for each child app 
.

Please help me establish a communication between these two shared workers.

I tried to use MessageChannel, but seems like it is used for webworkers.

```
<script>
    var channel = new MessageChannel();
    var worker1 = new SharedWorker('worker1.js');
    var worker2 = new SharedWorker('worker2.js');

    worker1.postMessage({
        command: 'connect'
    }, [channel.port1]);

    worker2.postMessage({
        command: 'connect'
    }, [channel.port2]);

    var sendMessage = function() {
            var message = document.getElementById('test').value();
            worker1.postMessage({
                command: "forward",
                message: message
            });
        }

</script>
```

Worker1 and 2

```
var otherWorker
var onMessageArrival = function(event) {
    console.log("Received a message: " + event.data);

};

self.onmessage = function(event) {
    switch (event.data.command) {
        // Setup connection to worker 2
        case "connect":
            otherWorker = event.ports[0];
            otherWorker.onmessage = onMessageArrival;
            break;

            // Forward messages to worker 2
        case "forward":
            // Forward messages to worker 2
            otherWorker.postMessage(event.data.message);
            break;

            //handle other messages from main
        default:
            console.log(event.data);
    }
};
```

Comment: It works in shared web workers as well. Please post the code that you tried and tell us what did not work.

Comment: I have added the code at: https://jsfiddle.net/ryzpmo9n/,
Thats a test package. Both sharedworker1 and sharedworker2 will be using the same code.

But i wanted to know if they can communicate with some chrome api or something, without the help of code in page.

Comment: What do you mean by "*but seems like it is used for webworkers.*"? Does the MessageChannel not work?

Comment: Code added, Thanks

Comment: You should be able to access the other worker without help of the code in page by simply instantiating the same `SharedWorker` from the worker scope, and then connect to it.

Comment: Thanks bergi, let me develop that idea.